# Can excel sheet be read by Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, excel, vba

I want to read an excel file using `JavaScript`. As we all know, IE supports following logic to read.

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("attachData.xlsx"); 
var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1"); 
repCount = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value; 
document.getElementById('div1').innerText = repCount;
```

But I want to make it cross-browser.Since the above lines of code does not work in other browsers, I was thinking to use Ajax request. I tried with the following piece of code:

```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST','../attachData.xlsx',true);       
   xhr.send();
   xhr.onreadystatechange= readystatechange;

   function readystatechange(){
     if(xhr.readyState === 4){
       console.log(xhr.response);
     }
   }
```

Here, the response comes `unreadable` format ( like `encoded`).Is there any other way to achieve this. My biggest concern is that can we read excel by ajax or not?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to create a page with for example php (good resource might be: http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/).

Then you could send an ajax request to that page with as parameter the url to the document. And the page would return the converted (json?) data.